# Issue in getting multiple dates in descending order with 2 table and 3 date field join

Tags: php, mysql, date, join

i want to list record with 2 tables and 3 diffrener date field i run below query for that

```
SELECT id, register.reg_date ,payment_history.payment_date ,paymentcancel_date  
FROM register 
LEFT JOIN payment_history ON payment_history.r_id = register.id 
WHERE user_type = 'Landlord' 
ORDER BY GREATEST(reg_date,paymentcancel_date,payment_date) DESC
```

and i get output like below image

[image]

but in above output date is not come in **decending order** i want output like below format

[image]

**EDIT**

```
SELECT id, register.reg_date ,payment_history.payment_date ,paymentcancel_date  from register  left join  payment_history on payment_history.r_id = register.id where user_type = 'Landlord' ORDER BY COALESCE(reg_date, '2000-01-01') desc,
              COALESCE(paymentcancel_date, '2000-01-01') desc,
              COALESCE(payment_date, '2000-01-01')
              desc
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you must have tried something!!!

Answer (score 0):

Alas, `GREATEST()` returns `NULL` if *any* arguments are `NULL`.  So, one way is something like this:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(reg_date, '2000-01-01'),
                  COALESCE(paymentcancel_date, '2000-01-01'),
                  COALESCE(payment_date, '2000-01-01')
                 ) desc
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff: i tried your code but it is not get result in descending order of all date fields.

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya . . . It should work for any dates in this century.  If you have older dates, then change the constant.  You can edit your question and show how it doesn't work.

Comment: see my edit portion i make change as per your query and i display output also now i want descending order of  payment_date column

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya . . . My `order by` has the function `greatest()`.  Yours does not.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue by below code

```
$res= $this->property_model->get_all_array("SELECT reg_date as date,f_name,id as id from register order by reg_date desc");
$res1= $this->property_model->get_all_array("SELECT payment_date as date,history_id,r_id as id from payment_history order by payment_date desc");
$data['activity'] = array_merge($res,$res1);

foreach ($activity as $key => $row) {
$volume[$key]  = $row['date'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $activity);
```